# FirebaseAuth authStateChange not emitting when signing out immediatly after log in

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am building an app where the authentication should be handled by firebase auth. However, I am running into an issue where the `authStateChange` stream does not emit after a sign out event. **Note** that I am testing this in conjunction with the Firebase Local Emulator.

This is my setup: in my main file I am trying to control whether the user sees a sign in page or the personalized content:

```
// ...
home: StreamBuilder<User?>(
  stream: FirebaseAuth.authStateChanges(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // do something about it
    }
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return _loadingScreen();
    }
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      // signed in
      return _buildContentPage();
    } else {
      // signed out
      return _buildSignInPage();
    }
  },
)
// ...
```

This works fine. However, in one of the child widgets of my `ContentPage` I have a sign out button with following logic:

```
void signOutPressed() async {
    // Show a snackbar or perform any other action
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Signed out')),
    );
    // Perform sign out action
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
```

When I press the button right after signing in, nothing in the UI changes.

Expected behavior would be to now see the `SignInPage` again. Printing `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` after the `signOut` prints `null`, meaning signing out was successful. Also, if I open another stream somewhere *after* signing in, it correctly emits after the button is pressed. Finally, if I press the button *after* signing in *and* performing a hot reload/app restart, everything works as expected.

Sadly, I did not yet have a chance to try this with a real Firebase connection or on a production build as I am just starting out. Anyway, this behavior seems odd to me and I am wondering whether I am missing something or whether there is a bug somewhere.

*The usual disclaimer: I am just starting out with Flutter, so please excuse any bad design decisions made. Happy to get tips on how to do it better.*